# How do I check if my pin exists in the SQL database while using asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to check if the number I'm passing into the database already exists. I'm using a submit button on my form which submits my text box that has the id="pin" which contains the number I'm checking for. However, every time I submit it it says the number exists even when it doesn't. Any tips on what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my aspx.cs code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        string connectionString = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-HOB2BSG\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=dogdata;Integrated Security=True";

        protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                sqlCon.Open();

                SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("RetrieveData", sqlCon);
                sqlCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pin", Int32.Parse(pin.Text.Trim()));

                sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                // check if pin exists
                using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) from dbo.tUser where pin = pin", sqlCon))
                {
                    int userCount = (int)sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();

                    if (userCount > 0)
                    {
                        Response.Write("<script>alert('Pin Exists!')</script>");
                        new SqlCommand("SELECT IMEI, Sim, DeviceNumber FROM dbo.tUser");
                    }

                    if (userCount < 1)
                    {
                        Response.Write("<script>alert('Pin Doesn't Exist')</script>");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can u post yout stored procedure

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) from dbo.tUser where pin = pin ` must be `SELECT COUNT(*) from dbo.tUser where pin = @pin`

Comment: `Response.Write` isn't going to work in ASP.net

Comment: Your pin value is not passing correct in if exists block...try pin= "+pin+" but its not safe

Comment: why are you creating 4 separate `SqlCommand`s one of which just gets instanciated and then ignored?!

Comment: Liam's right, lots of this makes no sense. What does the "RetrieveData" procedure do? If it "retrieves" data, then running it using "ExecuteNonQuery" makes no sense, because that's designed for queries which don't return results (e.g. insert, update, delete queries). So you ignore the result of that, but then create new SqlCommand which contains an incorrect query (as pointed out by Mihail) but then you never bind any parameter to it either. Then you randomly have another SqlCommand object (SELECT IMEI etc) which you just do nothing at all with. Not clear what this is for.

Comment: And Response.Write is not the correct way to update your page when using asp.net WebForms (which is what this is, it's not Razor, despite your erroneous tag). Instead you update a control on the page, which is represented by a variable in the C#. All of this suggests you don't really understand any of the basics - I suggest taking some WebForms and ADO.NET tutorials before going any further, as you seem quite confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your logic is a little off, try:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        sqlCon.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) from dbo.tUser where pin = @pin", sqlCon);
        sqlCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pin", Int32.Parse(pin.Text.Trim()));

        var count = (int)sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar();

        if (count > 0)
        {
            // Pin exists logic
        }
        if (count < 1)
        {
            // Pin doesn't exist logic
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good point. I was focussing on fixing the SQL part of the problem.